# Finding all non isomorphic graphs of a given degree sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Is there is a general way to draw all the non-isomorphic graphs of a given degree sequence?

We can use Havel Hakimi's algorithm to find graphs for a given degree sequence, but how do we find all the non-isomorphic graphs?

Comment: This is probably a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

Faradzhev, I. A.: Generation of nonisomorphic graphs with a given degree sequence. In: Algorithmic Studies in Combinatorics, Nauka, Moscow, 1978

Read, R. C.: Every one a Winner or how to Avoid Isomorphism Search when Cataloguing Combinatorial Configurations. Ann. Discr. Math. 2 (1978) 107-120

Colbourn, Ch. J.; Read, R. C.: Orderly algorithms for graph generation. 1979

for chemical molecules:
**[MOLGEN](http://www.molgen.de/)

[MOLGEN online](https://btmdx1.mat.uni-bayreuth.de/~alfred/molgenonline/)**
[Grund, R.; Kerber, A.; Laue, R.: Construction of Discrete Structures, Especially Isomers. 1996](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Construction-of-Discrete-Structures%2C-Especially-Grund-Kerber/0a11c63a29dd9d00e884afa475a9824f81236e53)

**[Sage Common Graphs:](http://sage-doc.sis.uta.fi/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html)

"Generate all graphs with a specified degree sequence"**
[McKay, B. D.: Isomorph-Free Exhaustive generation. J. Algor. 26 (1998) (2) 306-324](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Isomorph-Free-Exhaustive-Generation-McKay/912c1db970c67d997838ad8a1a65ffdec94784e9)^

**[Latapy, M.: Graph generation software](https://www-complexnetworks.lip6.fr/~latapy/FV/generation.html)**
[Viger, F.; Latapy, M.: Fast generation of random connected graphs with prescribed degrees. 2005](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0502085)
[Fabien Viger, F.; Latapy, M.: Efficient and simple generation of random simple
connected graphs with prescribed degree sequence. 2005](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01468081)

Isomorph-Free Exhaustive Generation. In: Kaski, P.; Östergård, P. R. J.: Classification Algorithms for Codes and Designs, Springer, 2006, 105-143

[Shin-ichi Nakano: Listing All Trees with Specified Degree Sequence. 2008](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Listing-All-Trees-with-Specified-Degree-Sequence-Nakano/cc58e88ef8f91af6da4a6044db8f14bca07892b3)

**[Király's Method for Generating All Graphs from a Degree Sequence](http://gilleain.blogspot.com/2012/07/kiralys-method-for-generating-all.html)**
[Király, Z.: Recognizing graphic degree sequences and generating all realizations. 2011](https://web.cs.elte.hu/egres/tr/egres-11-11.pdf)

**[Hartke, S.: Graph generation (2011?)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/regs/graphgen.html)**
[Hartke, S. G.: McKay's Canonical Graph Labeling Algorithm](http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/SAUCY/papers/Canonical.pdf)